# Keyboard event event.key is unidentified on android webview

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, webview

Try load webview with this html on react native

```
    <div
          tabindex="1"
          contenteditable="true"
          id="test-test"
          style="width: 300px; height: 300px;"
        >
   </div>
   <script>
          document
            .getElementById(“test-test”)
            .addEventListener(“keydown”, function (e) {
              alert(e.key || e.keyCode || “empty”);
            });
   </script>
```

event.key is unidentified or event.keyCode  is 229 always

Comment: Try `e.charCode`

Comment: charCode is always 0 for android keyboards

Comment: Try using `e.which`

Comment: its null none of these are working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its react-native then we can extend the webivew library and override the onCreateInputConnection method. For anyone who wants to extend webview here is the code

1. First create CustomWebviewManager.java file and add the content

package your-package-name;

```
import com.reactnativecommunity.webview.RNCWebViewManager;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ThemedReactContext;
import android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper;
import com.facebook.react.module.annotations.ReactModule;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputConnection;
import android.os.Build;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.webkit.ConsoleMessage;
import android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;


@ReactModule(name = CustomWebViewManager.REACT_CLASS)
public class CustomWebViewManager extends RNCWebViewManager {
  /* This name must match what we’re referring to in JS */
  protected static final String REACT_CLASS = “MyCustomWebView”;

  protected static class CustomWebViewClient extends RNCWebViewManager.RNCWebViewClient { }

  protected static class CustomWebView extends RNCWebViewManager.RNCWebView  {
    public CustomWebView(ThemedReactContext reactContext) {
      super(reactContext);
    }
    
    @Override
    public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {   
        return new BaseInputConnection(this, false);
    }
  }

  

  @Override
  protected RNCWebView createRNCWebViewInstance(ThemedReactContext reactContext) {
    return new CustomWebView(reactContext);
  }

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return REACT_CLASS;
  }



  @Override
  protected void addEventEmitters(ThemedReactContext reactContext, WebView view) {
    view.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
  }
}
```

2. Then create your own web view package file CustomWebViewPackage.java

   ```
    package your-package-name;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
    import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
    import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
    import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager;

    public class CustomWebViewPackage implements ReactPackage {
        @Override
        public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
          return Collections.emptyList();
        }

        @Override
        public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
          return Arrays.<ViewManager>asList(new CustomWebViewManager());
        }
    }
   ```

Then in your Webivew component Load it like this

```
MyCustomWebView = requireNativeComponent(‘MyCustomWebView’, MyNotesEditor,
    WebView.extraNativeComponentConfig);    

 <Webview
     nativeConfig={{component: MyCustomWebView}}
  />
```

Comment: Thanks! I used your comment to capture and send back the backspace key code. https://gist.github.com/dakhipp/72377353da53d9b106d705a0e8c64c81

Comment: I am glad that it helped you :)

Answer (score 5):

The is a [deliberate decision](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=118639#c239) from the Android touch keyboard implementation.

The only workaround is dealing the actual input text:

```js
inputElement.addEventListener('beforeinput', e => {
    if(e.inputType === 'deleteContentBackward') {
        // check whatever you want to check for
        if(!myCondition(e))
            e.preventDefault() // will block the deletion
    }
})
```

Comment: Can you provide me some example, in my case I just need to control backspace key that prevents users to delete characters based on some condition i tried beforeInput event but it did not prevent users to delete characters?

Comment: You can observe input changes and `e.preventDefault()` if the new text doesn't meet your condition

Comment: can you please provide me some sample code ? i mean should i create a observer or is there any event which can be cancelled ?

Comment: on event, read the text from input. cache it. compare the current text to the cache first, and derive the effective keypress (I'm assuming you mostly care about new input, not deletes). text substitution  will likely make detecting the change miss, but but can easily trap for that (probably resetting and scanning for your effective keypress). thats my read of it, based on that link

Comment: i just need to prevent delete and don’t care about new inputs, just want to disable backspace key on android mobile

Comment: So you'll need to check if the new text is the same as the old text minus a single character (keep in mind, it's not always the _last_ character)

Comment: but my question is how can I prevent delete operation. Mordechai can you provide me  some example of code ?

Comment: `e.preventDefault()`. I'll write some code when I have a moment later

Comment: e stand for which event ?

Comment: input changed event

Comment: yes but what type of listeners or event ? is it for keydown or keyup ?

Comment: `beforeinput` event type

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234422/discussion-between-bittu-and-mordechai).

Comment: beforeinput event has a bug on android we cannot cancel this event fully, that is when i press backbutton for long time it allows to delete multiple characters at a time

Comment: @Mordechai did you find any alternative solution ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, but if you wish to try, respond to actual text changes and see if looks like a backspace (a single character less than the previous input) and immediately change the text back to the old value if it doesn't meet your criteria

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's `react-native-webview` issue

[Keyboard event event.key is unidentified #1473](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/1473)

Comment: its not react-native-webview issue its issue with android chrome browser

Answer (score 0):

> When using virtual/mobile keyboards, formally known as IME (Input-Method Editor), the W3C standard states that a KeyboardEvent’s e.keyCode should be 229 and e.key should be "Unidentified".

Plus, e.key is deprecated; and if you want to support "all" browsers the [solution proposed by MSDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode#examples) is verbose.

**Alternative/effective approach**: Check the value, instead of the key. If you're using a framework to develop, listen to custom events like 'onChange' or 'ionInput'; evt.detail.value (where evt is a CustomEvent) will give you the char typed. If you're using vanilla components, see if you can work with the whole input value, like in the example below.

Here's an **example** of filtering input, to allow only alphanumeric chars:

```
const input = document.getElementById("myInput");
const regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;

input.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  const value = input.value;
  if (!value) {
    return;
  }
  if (regex.test(value)) {
    return;
  }
  input.value = value.replace(/[\W_]/g, "");
  event.preventDefault();
});
```